# How to split strings in a single field and create another field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have this

**complete address**

```
MUELLE, PUERTO GALERA

MUELLE, PUERTO GALERA

HUNDURA, PUERTO GALERA

HUNDURA, PUERTO GALERA
```

i want to have this kind of output

```
    address      |  municipality
----------------------------------    
    MUELLE       |  PUERTO GALERA

    MUELLE       |  PUERTO GALERA

    HUNDURA      |  PUERTO GALERA

    HUNDURA      |  PUERTO GALERA
```

| - is field border

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ',', 1) as address,SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ',', -1) as municipality FROM table